# Angularjs ng-click not firing, tried many solutions

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular. Trying to add ng-click to a burger menu. Checked many posts, didn't find proper solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/0b89qxx9/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="left-nav" ng-app="free">
  <div class="menuburger" ng-controller="menuburgerController" ng-click="menubClick" >
     <div class="menuburger-layer"></div>
     <div class="menuburger-layer"></div>
     <div class="menuburger-layer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var appFree = angular.module('free', []);
appFree.controller('menuburgerController', function($scope) {
  $scope.menubClick = function($scope) {
    alert('menu b clicked !')
  };
});
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you will need to change `ng-click="menubClick"` to `ng-click="menubClick()"`

Comment: It works! Thank you guys, you guys are brilliant !@Brian@Anvesh reddy@Nawsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answers tell you how to make it work, but none of them tells you ***why***.

Exactly as you have defined it in your controller,

```
$scope.menubClick = function(){
  // whatever
}
```

So, if you run `console.log($scope.menubClick)`, this is exactly what you will get, the function definition:

```
function(){// whatever}
```

Function definitions are just strings which can be stored in object properties. The object, in your case, is the controller's `$scope`. But you don't want the function definition, you want to run the function. That's why you need to add `()` to the variables' (that's holding the definition) name:

```
<... ng-click="menubClick()>
```

Using the function definition is not *incorrect* (you can actually use it to pass this script to some other object ***without running it***). But it's best you understand what you use, so you get the expected result.

Note: if your function has arguments, they will be passed correctly:

```
$scope.someFunc = function(a,b,c){}
// and, in view

ng-click="someFunc(a,b,c)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask click event is calling a function you should call with parenthesis.
ng-click="menubClick()".

Answer (score 1):

Use this line

```
<div class="menuburger" ng-controller="menuburger" ng-click="menubClick()" >
```

ng-click must call menubClick() with the brackets for it to work.